# Trying to make my entire site https

Tags: security

I am trying to make an entire Drupal site https.

I tried enabling secure pages, and this seems to work for every authenticated user.

However any anonymous user either gets only http, or possibly an infinite redirect if I wildcard all possible paths.

How do I get https:// to work on every page, for all users, including anonymous?

This is what my current .htaccess has in the mod_rewrite.c section:

```
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Secure pages is causing the problem. Remove it, and 301 all http to https at the web server level. It's that easy, no other config necessary

Comment: I removed secure pages and secure login. I've tried a directive in both my .htaccess in the site's webroot as well as a directive in the virtual host. Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually easier to redirect at the Apache level if you're looking to make the entire Drupal HTTPS. You can place this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I was still able to access http://

Comment: The flag was missing when I pasted the code. It's fixed now.

Comment: Nope, still able to access http://

Comment: Have you placed the rule after the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
& `RewriteEngine on` sections? Your instance of Apache may not have mod_rewrite on by default. It needs to be enabled for RewriteCond/RewriteRule to work.

Comment: Added my .htaccess.

Comment: Clive probably nailed it with the conflicting redirects. Make sure securepages is disabled.

Comment: It is. Disabled and uninstalled. Still not working.

Comment: In fact, I essentially deleted my entire .htaccess, and listening on port 80 entirely and for some reason it says site not found - for some reason the directives that are redirecting it to https are just not being picked up.

Comment: It sounds like a Apache hosting environment issue. I've never hit redirect snags with this RewriteRule, outside of mod_rewrite not being enabled. Here's [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite) on troubleshooting mod_rewrite.

Comment: I'm still getting redirected to https on Drupal login too, even with the modules uninstalled. Apache is such a headache.

Comment: Ok, figured out what the problem was - it was due to one of my sites using the default apache site configuration despite me thinking that it was turned off. When I fixed that, this worked, so I'm giving you the answer.