# Form state redirects do not respect https

Tags: 8, redirection

on some forms I added custom redirects, for example on the user login form:

```
function my_module_user_login_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('view.my_custom_view.page_1');
}
```

This is working well even with https on my test server: the user will be redirected after login to the view page with https, let's say https://my-domain.de/my-view-page

On another server the same is not working: on this server the domain is only reachable via https - not via http. This means calling http://my-domain.de will lead to a server error only using https://my-domain.de the project will be displayed. Now when I login I will be redirected to http://my-domain.de/my-view-page (without https) which leads to this server error.

I am sucessfully logged in: when I enter https://my-domain.de/my-view-page manually I can reach this know. When logout (I did not any changes here) the same appears: After logout the user gets redirected to http://my-domain.de.

Can somebody give me a hint what can be the problem on the second server?

Best,
Tobias

Comment: Check in settings.php the section "Reverse Proxy Configuration".

Comment: As the web root is never reached via http no changes in .htaccess or settings.php can help

Comment: Try `var_dump(\Drupal::request()->server->all());` on the second server and check for headers of a CDN.

Comment: The Drupal project is behind an AWS load balancer... I think this might be the hot tip...

Comment: OK, then you only need to tell Drupal to trust this reverse proxy in settings.php.

Answer (score 1):

> On another server the same is not working: on this server the domain
>   is only reachable via https - not via http

Perhaps a redirect to force HTTPS was not set up on your other server.

see [Enabling HTTP Secure (HTTPS)](https://www.drupal.org/https-information). You can do this by altering the `VirtualHost definitions` on your 2nd server:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName www.example.com
>     Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

or alternatively you can do it in the [.htaccess](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155796/trying-to-make-my-entire-site-https/155797#155797) file by adding:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

Comment: This adds a redirection and does not solve the core of the question: why I Drupal creating redirects to a non https URL? If Drupal would create the correct redirects there would be no need to do this redirect

Comment: PS: in .htaccess I cannot set this as I do not reach the web root folder calling the domain without https

Comment: @TobiasKrause Didn't you ask `Can somebody give me a hint what can be the problem on the second server?` you never asked why Drupal is creating redirects to non https url... Also, you say, `This means calling http://my-domain.de will lead to a server error` this is bad practice, it should redirect to https. In addition, if all is well on your test server, this most likely means Drupal is not the issue, and it's probably a server configuration issue on your other server. Like not doing what my answer says.